# Wget: Download all files starting with a specified name?

Tags: download, wget

How do I download all files starting with a specified name with `wget`?

For example, I have the link `https://mylink.com/directory/`.

There are the following files:

```
myFile_01_02.txt
myFile_01_03.txt
myFile3
yourFile
File1
secondFile
```

So, for example, I want to download all the files that starts with `myFile`. I read the `help` for the `wget` command but I didnt find anything useful. How can I do this?

Comment: The official docs on [filtering for specific files](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Types-of-Files). In short, the option would be something like `--accept 'myFile*'`.

Comment: @Anaksunaman so it doesnt work... I try `wget -A "myFile_*[0-9]{2}_[0-9]{2}*.txt" https://mylink.com/directory/` but it doesnt help

Comment: Use the accept-type option in conjunction with the mirroring or recursive options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments by @ivanivan, the [-A (--accept) series of options](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Types-of-Files) must be used in conjunction with the `-m` (mirror) or `-r` (recursive) options. Therefore, interpreting your example command, the command you would likely want would be e.g. `wget -m -nd -A "myFile_*_*.txt" https://mylink.com/directory/` (where `-nd` places all the matching files in a single directory rather than e.g. `/mylink.com/directory/file.txt`).

Comment: Thanks!! this really works.  I used the same as  "wget -m -nd -A "abcblas*.deb" http://myurls/mydir/list/alldebs/version-xxxx"